# jQuery shortening this query down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to shorten this query's down into one at all?

```
$('p:contains(Tel:)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('Tel:', '<strong>Tel:</strong>');
});
$('p:contains(Fax:)').html(function() {
    return $(this).html().replace('Fax:', '<strong>Fax:</strong>');
});
```

My code looks for Tel: and Fax: and wraps them with the `<strong>` tag

Comment: I don't get the two "off topic" close votes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can merge them as :

```
$('p:contains(Tel:), p:contains(Fax:)').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(Tel\:|Fax\:)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

But in fact this is a little redundant : you ask jQuery to make a first search before you do your own.

I would personally prefer this :

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    var changed = html.replace(/(Tel\:|Fax\:)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
    if (changed!=html) $(this).html(changed);
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ozoyap/1/edit) (click *"Run with JS"*)

Comment: As good as both look, I'm getting a syntax error on the lines with the regex

Comment: when using a callback with `.html()`, jquery passes an index and the current html to that callback. Using this, the first example could be rewritten as: `$('p:contains(Tel:), p:contains(Fax:)').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/(Tel\:|Fax\:)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});`. So there is no redundant call to `.html()` needed (demo: http://jsbin.com/uzexid/1/)

Comment: +1 This makes the first version better (I'll edit), but there is a redundant search. There is probably no performance problem with the first version but I personally prefer to be DRY, especially regarding researched tokens.